# Why won't this batch script run after login?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The project is a little command terminal with a login screen. However, after I get passed the login, it fails to open any more. Does anyone have any suggestions/fixes? (Also, I realize that parts of the code weren't made 100% by me)

```
@echo off
:LOGIN
set/p uname= < HoodedBlack
set/p pass=< Password
title Login
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo            HoodedBlack's Mainframe V0.1
echo                       Login
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
set/p "unamel=              Username :
set/p "passwordl=              Password :
echo.

IF "%passwordl%"=="Password" goto LOADING

IF NOT "%passwordl%"=="Password" 
goto ERROR


:ERROR
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                     Error
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo Invalid Username or password
echo An Admin has been notified of this attempt.   
pause




:LOADING
title Loading...
set load=%load%!!!!!!!
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Login
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo                 Username : %unamel%
echo                 Password : %passwordl%
echo.
echo.
echo          Logging in...
echo          ===================================
echo          %load%
echo          ===================================
echo.                              Please Wait...
echo.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==5 goto DONE
goto LOADING

:DONE
title Done
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Done
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo               #
echo             #
echo     #     #            Login Successfully
echo      #  #
echo       #
echo.
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------
pause
goto WELCOME

:WELCOME
title Welcome
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo  Welcome, HoodedBlack! Your rank is: Mainframe Owner
echo               Mainframe v0.1 HoodedBlack
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Hello!           
echo Say "cmds" for a list of commands
echo or say "exit" to exit the mainframe            
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If %INPUT%=="cmds" goto cmds
If NOT %INPUT%=="cmds"
then
If %INPUT%=="exit" goto exit
If NOT %INPUT%=="exit"
then
If %INPUT%=="DDoS" goto DDoS
If %INPUT%=="DDoS"
then
If %INPUT%=="DoS" goto DoS
If %INPUT%=="DoS"
then
If %INPUT%=="Password" goto pword
If NOT %INPUT%=="Password"
then pause




:cmds
title cmds
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Commands list
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo              DDoS: Redirects you to a ddos service.
echo              DoS: Sends a ping dos attack
echo                    (More commands coming soon!)
echo -------------------------------------------------
pause
goto WELCOME

:exit
title exit
exit  


:DDoS
start www.alphastress.com

:DoS
title cmds
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo            Ping attack (Denial Of Service)
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo Select an IP to send the attack to
echo 
echo -------------------------------------------------


:pword
title Password Generator
cls
echo I will make you a new password.
echo Please write the password down somewhere in case you forget it.
echo ----------------------------------------­-----------------------
echo 1) 1 Random Password
echo 2) 5 Random Passwords
echo 3) 10 Random Passwords
echo Input your choice
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto A if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==2 goto B if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==3 goto C if NOT goto Start2
:A
cls
echo Your password is %random%
echo Now choose what you want to do.
echo 1) Go back to the beginning
echo 2) Exit
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Start2 if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==2 goto Exit if NOT goto Start 2
:Exit
exit
:B
cls
echo Your 5 passwords are %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%.
echo Now choose what you want to do.
echo 1) Go back to the beginning
echo 2) Exit
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Start2 if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==2 goto Exit if NOT goto Start 2
:C
cls
echo Your 10 Passwords are %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%, %random%
echo Now choose what you want to do.
echo 1) Go back to the beginning
echo 2) Exit
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Start2 if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==2 goto Exit if NOT goto Start 2
```

Comment: You're missing closing quotes in your `uname1` and `password1` `set /p` lines, but that's in addition to what's _actually_ breaking your code. If you're going to have multi-line `if` statements like the one where you're verifying that `%password1%` is equal to "Password", you need parentheses.

Comment: @HoodedBlack While it might be useful to learn and write scripts in Windows Batch, you could also try PowerShell. Much easier to use, has great documentation and is very powerful. I'd advise you to try PowerShell and I'm sure that you are going to love it. BTW, PowerShell comes with Windows and you don't need to install anything to begin using it. See https://powershell.org/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **bahrep**...

HoodedBlack -> Some restructuring and some new commands to check out:

```
@echo off

setlocal
:MAIN_LOOP
call :LOGIN
if "%AUTHENTICATED%" == "TRUE" (
    call :LOADING
    call :WELCOME
    )
goto MAIN_LOOP
endlocal

goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:LOGIN
set UNAME=HoodedBlack
set PASS=Password
set AUTHENTICATED=TRUE
set UNAMEL=
set PASSWORDL=
title Login
cls
color 0a
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo            HoodedBlack's Mainframe V0.1
echo                       Login
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
set/p "UNAMEL=              Username :
set/p "PASSWORDL=              Password :
echo.

REM *** /i makes comparison non-case sensitive.
if /i "%UNAMEL%" NEQ "%UNAME%" set AUTHENTICATED=FALSE
if "%PASSWORDL%" NEQ "%PASS%"  set AUTHENTICATED=FALSE
if "%AUTHENTICATED%" == "TRUE" (
    call :LOGIN_OK
    goto END
    )

color 4e
title Access Denied
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                     Error
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo Invalid Username or password
echo An Admin has been notified of this attempt.   
echo.
echo Press any key.
pause>nul
goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:LOADING
title Loading...
set /a LOADNUM=0
set LOAD=
:LOAD_LOOP
set LOAD=%LOAD%!!!!!!!
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Login
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo                 Username : %unamel%
rem echo                 Password : %passwordl%
echo.
echo.
echo          Logging in...
echo          ===================================
echo          %LOAD%
echo          ===================================
echo.                              Please Wait...
echo.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /a LOADNUM+=1
if %LOADNUM% LSS 5 goto LOAD_LOOP
goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:LOGIN_OK
title Done
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Done
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo               #
echo             #
echo     #     #            Login Successfully
echo      #  #
echo       #
echo.
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------
pause
goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:WELCOME
title Welcome
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo  Welcome, HoodedBlack! Your rank is: Mainframe Owner
echo               Mainframe v0.1 HoodedBlack
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Hello!           
echo Say "cmds" for a list of commands
echo or say "exit" to exit the mainframe            
echo.
echo.
:INPUT_LOOP
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input:
if /i "%INPUT%" == "CMDS"     call :CMDS & goto INPUT_LOOP
if /i "%INPUT%" == "DDOS"     call :DDoS & goto INPUT_LOOP
if /i "%INPUT%" == "DOS"      call :DoS & goto INPUT_LOOP
if /i "%INPUT%" == "PASSWORD" call :pword & goto INPUT_LOOP
if /i "%INPUT%" == "EXIT"     goto END
echo Unrecognised command.
goto INPUT_LOOP
REM ****************************************************************************


:CMDS
title cmds
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo                       Commands list
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo              DDoS: Redirects you to a ddos service.
echo              DoS: Sends a ping dos attack
echo                    (More commands coming soon!)
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo.
goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:DDoS
start www.alphastress.com
goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:DoS
title cmds
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo            Ping attack (Denial Of Service)
echo -------------------------------------------------
echo Select an IP to send the attack to
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------
pause
goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:PWORD
title Password Generator
cls
echo I will make you a new password.
echo Please write the password down somewhere in case you forget it.
echo ----------------------------------------­-----------------------
echo 1) 1 Random Password
echo 2) 5 Random Passwords
echo 3) 10 Random Passwords
echo Input your choice
set INPUT=
set /p INPUT= Choice:

if "%INPUT%" == "1" (
    echo Your password is %RANDOM%.
    goto PASSWORD_DONE
    )
if "%INPUT%" == "2" (    
    echo Your 5 passwords are %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%.
    goto PASSWORD_DONE
    )
if "%INPUT%" == "3" (    
    echo Your 10 Passwords are %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%, %RANDOM%.
    goto PASSWORD_DONE
    )
echo Invalid option - press any key.
pause >nul
goto PWORD

:PASSWORD_DONE
echo.
goto END
REM ****************************************************************************


:END
REM ****************************************************************************
```

I agree with the PowerShell references above.  Windows' shell scripting is a bit finicky, mainly due to the fact that the more advanced stuff has been "stuck on", rather than "designed in".  One example of this is subroutines - yes, you can do them (see **call :SUBROUTINE_NAME** above), but they don't support a **return** statement.  Instead, you have to force the script to reach the end of the file, at which point the command interpreter realises that it has a return line number in its "stack".  This is why you'll see **goto END** above (the label **:END** could be any name).

Good luck!